# Cannot mount Obb on Android KitKat 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

The issue is already logged in the [Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61881).

Did somebody find a workaround?

It breaks multiple published apps on Google Play.

Comment: Comment [#5](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61881#c5) in linked tracker: _No workaround, ETA is sooner rather than later, and yes *it requires a new platform version*._

Comment: The thing is, i've downloaded couple of games which use APK expansion files and they still work on KitKat. Some guys are obviously making it work, though I guess they do it with the Android NDK.

Answer (score 2):

First a short clarification related to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20097166/cannot-mount-obb-on-android-kitkat-4-4#comment30428541_20097166) about some apps using APK expansion still working. Using an APK expansion file is not equal to mounting OBBs as a filesystem. An APK expansion file can be anything really, it's just a binary file.

Now to answer your question about a possible workaround. I just want to point out that if mounting OBBs does not work there is no simple one (i.e. without changing some code). Fortunately, the amount of code you would have to change is not that great and there are libraries out there that can assist you. So, to the point...

One use for the APK expansion files is obviously holding a filesystem inside, but you could just as well just concatenate your files into one big binary blob and save (like in a text file or in code) the position (*offset*) and length (byte *count*) of each file inside the APK expansion file. During runtime, whenever you need to read a certain file you just open the large binary file and read *count* bytes starting from the *offset*.

If you want the format to be more easily readable and not have to calculate the offsets and byte counts yourself, you could just use the ZIP file format, but with compression turned off (by setting compression = 0 in your ZIP tool of choice). There are actually classes in Android that can support you in easily reading your data from ZIP. You can read more about this method [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#ZipLib)